# Permission dialog not appearing when using Xamarin.Essentials in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am encountering an issue with Xamarin.Essentials in a Xamarin.Forms project where the permission dialog for StorageRead is not appearing as expected. The code seems to execute certain parts but skips the permission request dialog.

Code Sample:

```
await DisplayAlert("1", "1", "1");
var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    await DisplayAlert("2", "2", "2");
    var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
    if (result != null)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("3", "3", "3");
        // Additional code...
    }
}
else
{
    await DisplayAlert("4", "4", "4");
    // Request permission and await the result
    var permissionResult = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

    // Check if the permission was granted after the request
    if (permissionResult == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("5", "5", "5");
        var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
        if (result != null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("6", "6", "6");
            // Additional code...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("7", "7", "7");
    }
}
```

I have a Xamarin.Forms project where I'm using Xamarin.Essentials to request the StorageRead permission and then use the MediaPicker to pick a photo. However, I'm facing an issue where the permission dialog is not appearing as expected. The code seems to execute parts 1, 4, and 7 without showing any permission-related dialogs.

Comment: You are testing this on an Android 13+ device.

Comment: That may relate to this GitHub known issue : [Storage permissions Android 13 api 33](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2041). You may try zerokewl88's [workaround](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2041#issuecomment-1720711978)  to grant permission.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is targeting Android 13 and above, the storage permissions have now changed based on whether you want to access Video, Audio or Images.

For photos you will need the image permission i.e. `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`

More information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)

Also, make sure you read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_IMAGES

Comment: I read them but i couldn't understand what does those codes do. Can you write me a code?